# Error: Functions did not deploy properly (delete callable function)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a delete function into the firebase cloud functions but then I get this error `Error: Functions did not deploy properly`. I have installed all the dependences e.g firebase-tools. Some of the steps I went through setting up the project are in these:
[image: screenshot]

This is the code I am trying to deploy:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.mintAdminToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const uid = data.uid;

  const token = await admin
    .auth()
    .createCustomToken(uid, { admin: true });

  return { token };
});


exports.recursiveDelete = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Only allow admin users to execute this function.
    if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token && context.auth.token.admin)) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Must be an administrative user to initiate delete.'
      );
    }

    const path = data.path;
    console.log(
      `User ${context.auth.uid} has requested to delete path ${path}`
    );

    // Run a recursive delete on the given document or collection path.
    // The 'token' must be set in the functions config, and can be generated
    // at the command line by running 'firebase login:ci'.
    await firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      });

    return {
      path: path 
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As from the comments, running the following solved the problem

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Actually with the changes you suggested I got a syntax error with regards to this "=>". I removed it and then got the original error.

Comment: Oh right, and if you would remove the '=>' as well?

Comment: Another thing I was thinking of it might support a older version of the language and the async might not be available to it yet.?

Comment: I have found the solution. I had some help from google support. I was told to run these two commands in the functions directory: npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save <and>
npm install -g firebase-tools. I created a new project and then ran the commands before deploying.